# Can't unminimize window within Tiger VNC window

Tags: linux, vnc

I'm running Tiger VNC through Windows 7 to a linux box (RHEL6).  Within that, windows/apps can get maximized by mistake (haven't figured out how I keep doing it).  When maximized, no controls outside the app itself are visible (no window edges, no taskbar, no window manager controls, etc.  The whole screen is consumed).  I was completely panicked like I'd have to kill the entire VNC, but I can at least hit alt-F9 and reduce everything, but if I ever bring this particular app back it consumes everything again. How do I get out of this situation without having to kill the program and restart?

Comment: If you have “no window edges, no taskbar, no window manager controls, etc.”, the app isn’t maximized, it’s ***full screen**.*   (Or am I wrong? Are other windows visible?)   “F11” and (Alt)+(Enter) are common keyboard shortcuts for toggling full screen mode (is it possible that you’ve been hitting one of those?); see also [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1105255/309110 "Shortcut for window full screen on MATE?").

Comment: You are correct, "full screen" is the right term.  F11 does work for terminals, but has no effect on the windows in question here (I believe they are Qt windows, from Spyder and pyplot).